# Is setting value on fields of objects of projected collection supported in spring expression (SpEL)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Is setting value on objects of projected collection supported in spring expression (SpEL)?

I get the following error while trying to run a sample code.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1068E:(pos 1310742): the expression component '![comment]' is not assignable
```

What I am trying to do is - set a value on all of the objects which match certain criteria.
(the example below may not conform to best practices as I am trying to keep it simple and quick)

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SpELTest {

    public static class Person {
        public String name;
        public int age;
        public String comment;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
                '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person("Person 1", 10));
        people.add(new Person("Person 2", 20));
        people.add(new Person("Person 3", 30));
        people.add(new Person("Person 4", 40));
        people.add(new Person("Person 5", 50));
        people.add(new Person("Person 6", 60));
        people.add(new Person("Person 7", 70));
        people.add(new Person("Person 8", 80));

        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setVariable("people", people);

        // check the projected
        List<String> projected = (List<String>) parser.parseExpression("#people.?[age > 50].![name]").getValue(context);
        for (String p : projected) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }

        // use expression to set values
        parser.parseExpression("#people.?[age > 50].![comment]").setValue(context, "older than 50");

        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
Person 6
Person 7
Person 8
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1068E:(pos 1310742): the expression component '![comment]' is not assignable
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ValueRef$TypedValueHolderValueRef.setValue(ValueRef.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.setValue(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.setValue(SpelExpression.java:169)
    at com.test.SpELTest.main(SpELTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

First of all - you cannot make an assignment to projection of some simple property.

Let's consider following class:

```
class Person {
    String name
}
```

It would be possible to change `Person`s name by

```
person.name = "newValue"
```

But what you're trying to do is:

```
String projection = person.name
projection = "newValue"
```

This won't work.

The second thing is that you cannot assign value `older than 50` to a collection (`List`).
You are able to do something like this:

```
parser.parseExpression("(#people.?[age > 50 and comment == null])[0].comment")
      .setValue(context, "older than 50");
```

but this would change only the first item in resulted projection.

There's no simple way to do this by `SpEL`, but you can use some external functions by registering them via `context.registerFunction`. Such function could accept collection of `Person` object and perform mutation on them.